# Why can I send GraphQL requests from the Chrome Apollo extension but I can't with my own extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, graphql, apollo

I'm developing a chrome extension that sends existing GraphQL queries to a site.

Testing with the Apollo chrome extension, I managed to send my query correctly.

[image]

But when I do it via my script, I seem to get an authentication error: "*User is not a workspace admin*".

[image]

My query is called out of a *chrome.scripting.executeScript* and limited to:

```
const doSomething = async () => {
    
    const query = JSON.stringify({
        query: `MY QUERY`
    });
    const response = await fetch(TARGET_URL, {
        headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
        method: 'POST',
        body: query,
    });

    const responseJson = await response.json();
    console.log(responseJson);
    return responseJson.data;
};

chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, (tabs) => {

    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
        target: { tabId: tabs[0].id },
        func: doSomething
    }, (result) => {
        console.log(result[0].result);
    });
});

const responseJson = await response.json();
console.log(responseJson);
```

I think I'm missing an authentication step, but I don't understand why I have a difference between the Apollo extension and mine.

How does Apollo manage to execute its request? How can I update my script to achieve something similar?

Comment: It's because executeScript runs the code in the context of a content script in the web page. Make the request outside executeScript, not inside. Also make sure your host_permissions include or encompass this URL.

Comment: @wOxxOm I have edited my code to share more details about how the function is called. When I compare payload between Apollo and my script, I see that Apollo query has some `extensions` with `persistedQuery` information as well as a `operationName`. I guess that's why mine is not working, but not sure how to add such things...

Comment: You make the request inside executeScript i.e. inside the code (function) injected by executeScript.

Comment: The Devtools don't actually make the request - they use the Apollo Client instance of your website to make the request. That might be the difference here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @phry mentioned, we send the request through your Apollo Client instance detected by the Chrome extension (whatever is set to `window.__APOLLO_CLIENT__`). This means that the request will go through your [link chain](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/link/introduction) as well, which may include some logic to attach authentication headers to the request.

Looking at your code sample, I don't see any additional header information set in your `fetch` request, so that request is likely not authenticated the same way. If you want to check what your app's Apollo Client instance is sending, you can override the [`fetch` function](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/link/apollo-link-http#customizing-fetch) on [`HttpLink`](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/link/apollo-link-http) and log the request.

```js
createHttpLink({
  fetch: (uri, options) => {
    console.log(uri, options)

    return window.fetch(uri, options);
  }
})

// or if you use the constructor to create the link
new HttpLink({
  fetch: (uri, options) => {
    console.log(uri, options)

    return window.fetch(uri, options);
  }
})
```

Just make sure the `fetch` function in your script includes any of the needed authentication headers that you see here. Hope this helps!

Comment: Very clear, thank you for the explanations. the issue was indeed in the fetch options.

Comment: Awesome! Glad this helped!